# Update woocommerce Cart with ajax

Tags: ajax, woocommerce, cart

Am using the following shortcode for displaying the cart

```
[woocommerce_cart]
```

And also am using https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woocommerce-ajax-cart plugin. When there is no products and am clicking on the button to see the Cart items it shows that the cart is empty but when am refreshing the page am getting that added product.

When i already have one product in the cart it is refreshed by ajax but when no products it did not work.

Any idea why?

Thanks in advance.